# is it an anti-pattern to cast between interfaces that are related but not identical regarding the signatures?

Tags: c#, software-design

First I'm new to the concept of programming against abstractions.

suppose i have the following:

```
public interface IEmail {}

public interface IEmailWithAttachments : IEmail
{
    List<Attachment> Attachments {get; set;}
}

public interface IService
{
    void Send(IEmail email);
}
```

EmailService class sends notifications of type IEmail and to do this it uses an SmtpClient which can only send objects of type MailMessage, that's why I used a factory to return a MailMessage instance that simply contains the properties values of the passed IEmail object.

```
public class EmailService : IService
{
    private IMailMessageFactory _mailMessageFactory;
    private ISmtpClient _smtpClient;

    public EmailService(ISmtpClient smtpClient, IMailMessageFactory mailMessageFactory)
    {
        _mailMessageFactory = mailMessageFactory;              
        _smtpClient = smtpClient;
    }
    public void Send(IEmail email)
    {
        using(MailMessage mailMessage = _mailMessageFactory.CreateMailMessageFromNotification(email))
        {
             _smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }

}

public interface IMailMessageFactory
{
    MailMessage CreateMailMessageFromNotification(IEmail email);
}

public class MailMessageFactory : IMailMessageFactory
{
    public MailMessage CreateMailMessageFromNotification(IEmail email)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

        //copies the IEmail properties to the new created MailMessage instance

        return mailMessage;
    }
}
```

**the question:**

as far as i know, IEmailWithAttachment is a different type than IEmail, should the factory method check if the passed IEmail object of type IEmailWithAttachment so I can access the attachment list property? like follows:

```
public class MailMessageFactory : IMailMessageFactory
{
    public MailMessage CreateMailMessageFromNotification(IEmail email)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

        //copies the IEmail properties to the new created MailMessage instance

        IEmailWithAttachment emailWithAttachment = email as IEmailWithAttachment;
        if (emailWithAttachment != null)
            {
                foreach (var attachment in emailWithAttachment.Attachments)
                {
                    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                }
            }
        return mailMessage;
    }
}
```

**OR** should I create another factory method that takes care of IEmailWithAttachments type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can often use 'is-a' vs 'has-a' as indicatiors as to whether you should use inhertance or not. If something 'is-a' somthing else, inhertance is good. If it 'has-a' thing, aggregation is better (aggregation means including one thing in the other as a property). Since an attachment isn't an email but an email can have an attachment, I would have the attachment be a property on the email. Using inheritance isn't a good idea in this case imo.

Comment: If I were designing this then I would make the Attachment an (optional) property of the Email. Or even give it a collection of Attachments, in case you need to allow for multiple attachments, which is impossible with your current design.

Comment: it's actually a list but i missed this clarification

Comment: I edited the question and please keep in mind that I have another implementations of IEmail that should not have attachments at all.

Comment: @HansKilian do you mean that I have to have IAttachmentsCollection as a property within the IEmailWithAttachments interface? because IAttachmentsCollection is not an Email at the end?

Comment: @Rasheed Yes, that's what I meant. I think that would be better.

Comment: @HansKilian thank you!
and what do you think about the second part of my question? should the same factory method do the check with the as operator?

Comment: Somewhere, the dicission has to be made how to create a MailMessage from the IEMail instance. The MailMessageFactory seems a perfect fit. So I would in fact use 1 factory for all types of IEMail. That's what factories are for. Just think about if you had 2 factories. Would that also require 2 Services (as the service currently only has 1 factory)? And a user would have to decide which service to call?

Comment: @king_nak thank you for your comment, actually each service will have only one factory "instance"  and I was wondering if the cast using the "As" operator is legit or would it be better to provide another CreateMailMessageFromNotification method that accepts other types like IEmailWithAttachments as parameter?

Comment: As IEmailWithAttachments inherits IEmail (which makes sense), you could get ambiguous calls with two methods. Also, the caller would have to know which method to use. When you add more layers of indirection, that `as` operator would just be on another level. So in my opinion, this is a good way to solve the problem (others might argue that type checking is always a code-smell. But this is a reasonable use case IMO)

Comment: @king_nak thank you for providing your insights about the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I fail to see way `IEmailWithAttachments` is a seperate interface from `IEmail` as it is valid for a email to have zero attachments.    If the two interfaces are combined, then the design problem of wishing to advoid a cast is no longer an issue.

Comment: you're absolutely right, but the logic that I have in production code is different based on what I want to send, in my scenario there are emails that should not have attachments, so I wanted to provide both implementations.
one with and one without attachments.

Comment: Maybe add a CanHaveAttachment property to the IEmail interface, so you can still have two different implementation classes.